# Why can there be holomorphic modular forms of negative half integral weight?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, eisenstein-series

In Shimura's paper "ON THE HOLOMORPHY OF CERTAIN DIRICHLET SERIES", he constructed a family of Eisenstein series $E(z,s)$ by summing factor of automorphy. $E(z,s)$ is of negative half-integral weight, and we can reconstruct it from the principal series of $\widetilde{SL_2}$. But $E(z,s)^2$ is a holomorphic modular form of negative integral weight, which must be $0$. I am very confused and would like to know what's the problem in my argument?

Comment: Shimura says that $E(z,s)$ is holomorphic in $s$, but that is not relevant to your question, as far as I can see. Do you mean to say that the specialization to $s = 0$, $E(z,0)$, is holomorphic? This is the only value of $s$ where the defining summation looks holomorphic in $z$. However, I could not see where in this paper Shimura claims that $E(z,0)$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, I mean the specialization at $s=0$. In the paper, Shimura computed the Fourier expansion of $E^*(z,0)$. For positive weights, we can also see that $E(z,0)$ is holomorphic from formula (1.4). For the negative weights, which are used to give the integral representation of the adjoint lifting, Shimura claims a functional equation relating positive and negative weight at p.93. One can also from the formulas of  Lemma 3, p.288, Elementary theory of L-function and Eisenstein series to see that $E(z,0)$ should be holomorphic for positive and negative weight.

Comment: I have no time to look into this paper, but let me point out that the usual Eisenstein series $E(z,s)$ is not holomorphic in $z$. Instead, it is an eigenfunction of the Laplace operator with eigenvalue $s(1-s)$.

Comment: @Alice The formula (1.4) does not prove holomorphy, as it is not absolutely convergent, just like how classical $E_2$ is not holomorphic. Similarly, I don't know if the Fourier expansion converges absolutely for $k$ negative, so even if each individual term were holomorphic, I don't know if the sum is. I can't tell if the functional equations prove holomorphy, as they don't just switch positive and negative $k$, but also change $s$ and introduce a complex conjugate.